# Trying to create a text box vector shape

Tags: inkscape, text

[image]

I am looking to make a shape like this on Inkscape, does anyone have any tips on how best to tackle this?

I have tried to input this into my design but it covers images I already have on the design as it imports in as a rectangle image with white corners.

Comment: Try using Trace Bitmap. It should do what you need with a fairly simple shape like this. I'm not at my PC so can't check, but it's either on the Paths or Objects menu.

Answer (score 3):

So you have a symmetric figure, 1 shape of corner, rotated 4 times by 90 degrees.

The one corner can be divided into 2 similar bezier curves. It's up to you to draw just one of them, copy it, turn it by 90°, flip and adjust it and then manipulate the endpoint, or draw both of them independently with the bezier tool.

Then you combine both objects, clone that, flip it horizontally. Adjust.

Combine again, clone, flip it vertically. Adjust again.

If you clone it, instead of just making copies, you can manipulate the first shape and the other clones will change their shape accordingly (not live, but on finishing each step of manipulation).

[image]